# type tab while sending a command to terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu

I want to write a program that every time a new device is mounted, it automatically unmounts and reformats it in ext4. I'm working on creating a solution for detecting mounting from someone else's question, but I still don't know how to get a tab input. I need it because every SD card will have a different name, so maybe if there's a different way to do that without using tab that'd be fine as well. This will be used in ubuntu 18.04.1.

```
package ReformatSDs;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReformatSDs
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        String command = "umount /media/dev/xxxx-xxxx";//this is where I need the tab input to replace the xxxx-xxxx

        String command2 = "sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk2p1";
               
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                       
            Process proc2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);            

            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader reader2 =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc3.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
        }

        proc.waitFor(); 
    }
    
}`
```